# Airflow Dag won't move past "queued" state

Tags: python, airflow

This code was working just fine a couple hours ago, but suddenly my dags started getting stuck in "queued" state.

Here's what I'm trying to run (i am only triggering manually):

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime as dt

def test_function():
    print('Hello there')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}

with DAG(
    'test',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A dag used for testing...',
    start_date=dt(2022, 5, 23),
    tags=['example'],
    catchup=False
) as dag:

    start = PythonOperator(
        task_id='test',
        python_callable=test_function,
        dag=dag
    )

    start
```

Here's what it looks like when it gets stuck.

[image]

If I replace the `PythonOperator` with a `PostgresOperator` it gets stuck as well.

The `DummyOperator` runs just fine.

Inside the Instance Details it says: `Task is in the 'queued' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.`

Edit:
So I've realized that every hour it starts working again. If I modify the file though (something as simple as moving the location of the `test_function` definition) it will get stuck again for another hour before it starts working again.

Comment: The reason why it got stuck may be on the task instance details page.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I've added info from the task instance to my answer. If there's some parameter in there that is more helpful let me know and I'll post its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your start date is `2017-01-01`, and the dag does not have `catchup=False` - the scheduler is scheduling the DAG for every day it hasn't been run since this date.

A DAG by default has a limit on the number of concurrent DAG instances it can run, so all the tasks are queued.

Is this what you wanted? You can either set `catchup=False` in the `DAG()` instance, which will only run the DAG for the current data interval, or increase the number of `max_active_runs` by passing this as a parameter to the `DAG()` instance as well.

Comment: I've added `catchup=False` and changed it to `start_date=2022-05-23` and it is still stalling :(

Comment: You'll need to reboot/kill the scheduler and workers after changing it. Any DAGs currently in a running state aren't updated when you change the source code.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?